# Why is the partition method adding a nil to the end of the array?

Tags: ruby, return-value

I am trying to use the partition [enumerable method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to separate an array into two different arrays. the left array is working correctly.

```
def quicksort(array)
  pivot = array.delete_at(6)
  left, right = array.partition { |x| x < pivot }
  puts "right's size"
  puts right.size
  puts 'right'
  puts right 
end

r = [14, 6, 41, 0, 5, 7294, 4, 25, 12, 24, 5, 2, 62, 67, 32, 78, 63, 3] 
p quicksort(r)
```

And here is the result from irb

```
right's size
14
right
14
6
41
5
7294
25
12
24
5
62
67
32
78
63
nil
```

What is causing the `nil` to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `nil` is not an element of the `array`, but return value of the method.

Since you are not returning anything from `quicksort`, it is returning `nil`.

Writing an object to return at the end will return that object and not `nil`, e.g.

```
def quicksort(array)
  pivot = array.delete_at(6)
  left, right = array.partition { |x| x < pivot }
  puts "right's size"
  puts right.size
  puts 'right'
  puts right 
  array
end
```

Also, removing `p` while calling the method will also help.

just do `quicksort(array)` instead of `p quicksort(array)`

Answer (score 4):

`p quicksort(r)` outputs the return value of `quicksort(r)`, which is the evaluated value of the last line in the definition of `quicksort`: `puts right`. The method `puts` always returns `nil`.